# MOA's StreamKM clustering doesn't return any result

Tags: java, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, weka, moa

I'm currently trying to cluster a great amount of data points into a given amount of clusters and I wanted to try MOA's streaming based k-means [`StreamKM`](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~abifet/MOA/API/classmoa_1_1clusterers_1_1streamkm_1_1_stream_k_m.html). A very simple example of what I'm trying to do using random data looks as follows:

```
StreamKM streamKM = new StreamKM();
streamKM.numClustersOption.setValue(5); // default setting
streamKM.widthOption.setValue(100000); // default setting
streamKM.prepareForUse();
for (int i = 0; i < 150000; i++) {
    streamKM.trainOnInstanceImpl(randomInstance(2));
}
Clustering result = streamKM.getClusteringResult();
System.out.println("size = " + result.size());
System.out.println("dimension = " + result.dimension());
```

The random instances are created as follows:

```
static DenseInstance randomInstance(int size) {
    DenseInstance instance = new DenseInstance(size);
    for (int idx = 0; idx < size; idx++) {
        instance.setValue(idx, Math.random());
    }
    return instance;
}
```

However, when running the given code, no clusters seem to be created:

```
System.out.println("size = " + result.size()); // size = 0
System.out.println("dimension = " + result.dimension()); // NPE
```

Is there anything else I need to take care of, or do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the MOA clustering concepts?

Comment: Use the source, Luke. MOA is open-source.

Comment: The code is not really that explained, and the MOA docs lack of usage examples... it's really difficult to understand how the algorithms have to be used. Moreover, I could not find any tutorial either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `prepareForUse()` method is not the correct method that initialize the algorithm.

Instead of `streamKM.prepareForUse();` , you should use `streamKM.resetLearning();`.

In short, your code should be like:

```java
StreamKM streamKM = new StreamKM();
streamKM.numClustersOption.setValue(5); // default setting
streamKM.widthOption.setValue(100000); // default setting
streamKM. resetLearning(); // UPDATED CODE LINE !!!
for (int i = 0; i < 150000; i++) {
    streamKM.trainOnInstanceImpl(randomInstance(2));
}
Clustering result = streamKM.getClusteringResult();
System.out.println("size = " + result.size());
System.out.println("dimension = " + result.dimension());
```

Comment: Wasn't able to test personally, but: Accepted. Thanks and sorry for missing this :-)